# Use dll that must be registered on Azure

Tags: azure, dll, azure-web-app-service

Originally I was going to deploy a new system I am creating straight into Azure app services

However part of the system needs to get data from a third party via a dll which is registered with regsvr

Is there any way of doing this or avoiding this?

I think I have to create a virtual machine?

Paul

Answer (score 1):

Due to the way the AppService Sandbox works, you cannot execute a regsvr operation.

See also:
[SQLXML on Azure Web sites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42902291/sqlxml-on-azure-web-sites/42943430#42943430)

General information about the sandbox:
https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox

If you need this component, and want to avoid using virtual machines, you could try hosting the component as a web API inside a [Azure Service Fabric cluster](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/service-fabric/).
You can use OWIN to host the API, and it should be possible to register your dll via startup tasks.

[Azure Service Fabric register COM component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42400613/azure-service-fabric-register-com-component)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cloud-services-migration-worker-role-stateless-service#startup-tasks

Depending on your application, you could either host everything in the service fabric API, or host only the component as an API there, while providing the actual application inside as Azure AppService.